# with libcxx and std::atomic, how does clearing of std::atomic_flag via default constructor work?

Tags: c++

I'm having a little trouble understanding something with C++ atomics, specifically with regards to libcxx10.  In running the libcxx tests related to atomics for validation purpose, I found a test that is supposed to make sure that the default constructor for an atomic_flag zeros out the value.   First I'm not sure if that is even a valid test as I read another stack overflow article that indicated that atomic values aren't guaranteed to be zero-initialized until C++20.

Does anyone know if atomic values even need to be initialized in older versions of the standard?

that said the libcxx tests do expect it to be zero initialized.   That implies the library should zero-initialize it.   But I'm having a hard time figuring out how it does that.

this is libcxx version 10.   I'm going to give snippets of the library code to show why I'm confused and maybe give enough info for someone to unconfuse me.

here is the body of the test that makes the claim that default initializing should zero it:

```
typedef std::atomic_flag A;
TEST_ALIGNAS_TYPE(A) char storage[sizeof(A)] = {1};
A& zero = *new (storage) A();
assert(!zero.test_and_set());
zero.~A();
```

So the quest to understand how that could work starts with std::atomic_flag.  here _LIBCPP_ATOMIC_FLAG_TYPE = bool which is understood to be lock-free for purposes of this discussion.

```
typedef struct atomic_flag
{
    __cxx_atomic_impl<_LIBCPP_ATOMIC_FLAG_TYPE> __a_;
   { stuff elided }
};
```

this depends on __cxx_atomic_impl<_Tp>.   This is the simplified version that deals with lock-free types:

```
template <typename _Tp,
          typename _Base = __cxx_atomic_base_impl<_Tp> >
struct __cxx_atomic_impl : public _Base {

  _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __cxx_atomic_impl() _NOEXCEPT _LIBCPP_DEFAULT
  _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR explicit __cxx_atomic_impl(_Tp value) _NOEXCEPT
    : _Base(value) {}
};
```

this depends on __cxx_atomic_base_impl<_Tp>, and here is where the value is defined.

```
template <typename _Tp>
struct __cxx_atomic_base_impl {

  _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
#ifndef _LIBCPP_CXX03_LANG
    __cxx_atomic_base_impl() _NOEXCEPT = default;
#else
    __cxx_atomic_base_impl() _NOEXCEPT : __a_value() {}
#endif // _LIBCPP_CXX03_LANG
  _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR explicit __cxx_atomic_base_impl(_Tp value) _NOEXCEPT
    : __a_value(value) {}
  _LIBCPP_DISABLE_EXTENSION_WARNING _Atomic(_Tp) __a_value;
};
```

the value is stored in __a_value in this class.

Note there are two code paths, one for c++03 and one for C++11 and beyond.

The path for C++03 does explicitly clear __a_value in the constructor, so we are good there.
But the path for C++11 and beyond only defaults the default constructor.   as far as I know a defaulted default constructor default-initializes members which is not the same as zero initialization.   In fact it does nothing for scalars...  (_Tp is bool here from the definition of std::atomic_flag)

and as far as I know defining something with the _Atomic keyword does not zero initialize it either.

Nor is there a member initializer.

Yet somehow the value is supposed to get initialized to zero, so that the tests will pass.   What am I missing?

Comment: What is the type `_Atomic(_Tp)`?  Does that have a default constructor that preforms zero initialization?

Comment: _Tp is bool.    So _Atomic(_Tp) would be whatever the C11 compiler does with atomics.    AFAIK that doesn't mean zero initialization although I could be wrong I suppose...

Comment: `_Atomic(...)` is going to have to result to a type.  Check out what `_Atomic()` is and what type you get from it.  Once we know that, we can find out if it is something that gets zeroed for you.

Comment: AFAIK _Atomic is a compiler intrinsic that marks the given type to tell the compiler it is an atomic type (it is in the C11 standard but is extended to C++ as well e.g. by clang).   So the resulting type would be bool with  an atomic modifier.